# Why do I get a SQL error near "LIMIT" in Redshift when I don't include the word "limit" anywhere in the query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have tried to run the following SQL query in Amazon Redshift serverless many times now and it keeps failing:

```
with ssr as
 (select s_store_id,
        sum(sales_price) as sales,
        sum(profit) as profit,
        sum(return_amt) as returns,
        sum(net_loss) as profit_loss
 from
  ( select  ss_store_sk as store_sk,
            ss_sold_date_sk  as date_sk,
            ss_ext_sales_price as sales_price,
            ss_net_profit as profit,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as return_amt,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as net_loss
    from store_sales
    union all
    select json_data.sr_customer_sk::bigint as store_sk,
        sr_returned_date_sk as date_sk,
        cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as sales_price,
        cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as profit,
        json_data.sr_return_amt::decimal(7,2) as return_amt,
        json_data.sr_net_loss::decimal(7,2) as net_loss
    from store_returns_json
   ) salesreturns,
     date_dim,
     store
 where date_sk = d_date_sk
       and d_date between cast('1998-08-04' as date) 
                  and dateadd(day, 14, cast('1998-08-04' as date))
       and store_sk = s_store_sk
 group by s_store_id)
 ,
 csr as
 (select cp_catalog_page_id,
        sum(sales_price) as sales,
        sum(profit) as profit,
        sum(return_amt) as returns,
        sum(net_loss) as profit_loss
 from
  ( select  cs_catalog_page_sk as page_sk,
            cs_sold_date_sk  as date_sk,
            cs_ext_sales_price as sales_price,
            cs_net_profit as profit,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as return_amt,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as net_loss
    from catalog_sales
    union all
    select cr_catalog_page_sk as page_sk,
           cr_returned_date_sk as date_sk,
           cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as sales_price,
           cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as profit,
           cr_return_amount as return_amt,
           cr_net_loss as net_loss
    from catalog_returns
   ) salesreturns,
     date_dim,
     catalog_page
 where date_sk = d_date_sk
       and d_date between cast('1998-08-04' as date)
                  and dateadd(day, 14, cast('1998-08-04' as date))
       and page_sk = cp_catalog_page_sk
 group by cp_catalog_page_id)
 ,
 wsr as
 (select web_site_id,
        sum(sales_price) as sales,
        sum(profit) as profit,
        sum(return_amt) as returns,
        sum(net_loss) as profit_loss
 from
  ( select  ws_web_site_sk as wsr_web_site_sk,
            ws_sold_date_sk  as date_sk,
            ws_ext_sales_price as sales_price,
            ws_net_profit as profit,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as return_amt,
            cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as net_loss
    from web_sales
    union all
    select ws_web_site_sk as wsr_web_site_sk,
           wr_returned_date_sk as date_sk,
           cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as sales_price,
           cast(0 as decimal(7,2)) as profit,
           wr_return_amt as return_amt,
           wr_net_loss as net_loss
    from web_returns left outer join web_sales on
         ( wr_item_sk = ws_item_sk
           and wr_order_number = ws_order_number)
   ) salesreturns,
     date_dim,
     web_site
 where date_sk = d_date_sk
       and d_date between cast('1998-08-04' as date)
                  and dateadd(day, 14, cast('1998-08-04' as date))
       and wsr_web_site_sk = web_site_sk
 group by web_site_id)
select channel as xchannel
        , id as xid
        , sum(sales) as xsales
        , sum(returns) as xreturns
        , sum(profit) as xprofit
 from 
 (select 'store channel' as channel
        , 'store' || s_store_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from   ssr
 union all
 select 'catalog channel' as channel
        , 'catalog_page' || cp_catalog_page_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from  csr
 union all
 select 'web channel' as channel
        , 'web_site' || web_site_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from   wsr
 )
 group by (xchannel,xid)
  union all
  select channel as xchannel
        , 'All' as xid
        , sum(sales) as xsales
        , sum(returns) as xreturns
        , sum(profit) as xprofit
 from
(
 select 'store channel' as channel
        , 'store' || s_store_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from   ssr
 union all
 select 'catalog channel' as channel
        , 'catalog_page' || cp_catalog_page_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from  csr
 union all
 select 'web channel' as channel
        , 'web_site' || web_site_id as id
        , sales
        , returns
        , (profit - profit_loss) as profit
 from   wsr
)
 group by (xchannel)
 --order by xchannel,xid
 ;
```

The error message states "Detail: SQL reparse error. Where: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"."

However, I don't even have the word "limit" in the query. Also, I've confirmed that the individual parts of the query all work up to the point at which "SKETCHY STUFF" is commented. Below there is where the issue is, but I can't isolate it further.

I think the core issue here probably has something to do with maybe an underlying expected piece of syntax, but I don't even know how further to explore that, as the word "limit" (which I know would be incorrect PostgreSQL syntax) is not even in this query and I don't see how it's relevant to whatever is breaking the query.

Does anyone know why I would be getting an error relating to the word "limit" when that isn't even in the query?

Comment: If you run each SELECT statement individually, do they all execute successfully?

Comment: The select statements with "store channel", "catalog channel" and "web channel" all fail

Comment: So that’s presumably where the problem lies. What error message(s) do these statements give?

Comment: To clarify why you're see `limit` errors: If you run your query in the Redshift Query Editor or other SQL tools such as dbeaver, they will add a limit clause in many cases to limit the amount of data requested.

Comment: I still seem to get the limit error.

Comment: On all 3 of those select statements?

Comment: When I used the ssr, csr, and wsr definitions with their corresponding queries in 3 different small queries, everything ran well. Notably, the following piece of code wasn't included in any of those runs and the three queries weren't unioned: select channel as xchannel
        , id as xid
        , sum(sales) as xsales
        , sum(returns) as xreturns
        , sum(profit) as xprofit